# Get element from arbitrary index in set

Tags: c++, stl

I have a set of type `set<int>` and I want to get an iterator to someplace that is not the beginning.

I am doing the following:

```
set<int>::iterator it = myset.begin() + 5;
```

I am curious why this is not working and what is the correct way to get an iterator to where I want it.

Comment: C and C++ are not the same language.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`myset.begin() + 5;` only works for random access iterators, which the iterators from `std::set` are not.

For input iterators, there's the function `std::advance`:

```
set<int>::iterator it = myset.begin();
std::advance(it, 5); // now it is advanced by five
```

In C++11, there's also `std::next` which is similar but doesn't change its argument:

```
auto it = std::next(myset.begin(), 5);
```

`std::next` requires a forward iterator. But since `std::set<int>::iterator` is a bidirectional iterator, both `advance` and `next` will work.

Comment: @"R. Martinho Fernandes" aren't these methods of linear time complexity? I'm wondering if there is some method which works in logrithmic time because sets are, after all, Balanced binary Trees?

Answer (score 0):

The operator+ doesn’t define for this structure and only It make sense for random access iterators.

First solution:
You can use [std::advance](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/advance/), the function uses repeatedly the increase or decrease operator (operator++ or operator--) until n elements have been advanced.

```
set<int>::iterator it = myset.begin();
std::advance(it, 5);
std::out << *it << std::endl; // == it + 5
```

Second solution:
Use [std::next](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/next/) or [std::prev](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/prev/) functions,The performance same as the old one because uses repeatedly the increase or decrease operator (operator++ or operator--)until n element have been advanced.

> Note: If it is a random access iterator, the function just uses just
>   once operator+ or operator-.

```
set<int>::iterator it1 = myset.begin();
std::next(it1, 5); // == it1 + 5 
std::out << *it1 << std::endl; // == it1 + 5

set<int>::iterator it2 = myset.end();
std::prev(it2, 5); // == it2 - 5
std::out << *it2 << std::endl; // == it2 - 5
```

> Note: If you want to access, [vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/?kw=vector) are very efficient accessing its elements (just like arrays) and relatively efficient adding or removing elements from its end.

Answer (score -1):

### **Get element at index from C++11 std::set**

`std::set` in C++ has no getter by index so you'll have to roll your own by iterating the list yourself and copying into an array then indexing that.

For example:

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<set> 
using namespace std; 
int main(){ 

    set<int> uniqueItems;        //instantiate a new empty set of integers 
    uniqueItems.insert(10); 
    uniqueItems.insert(20);      //insert three values into the set 
    uniqueItems.insert(30); 

    int myarray[uniqueItems.size()];    //create an int array of same size as the  
                                        //set<int> to accomodate elements 

    int i = 0;  
    for (const int &num : uniqueItems){ //iterate over the set 
        myarray[i] = num;               //assign it to the appropriate array 
        i++;                            //element and increment 
    }   

    cout << myarray[0] << endl;   //get index at zero, prints 10 
    cout << myarray[1] << endl;   //get index at one, prints 20 
    cout << myarray[2] << endl;   //get index at two, prints 30 

}
```

Or a handy dandy function to step through then return the right one:

```
int getSetAtIndex(set<int> myset, int index){ 
    int i = 0;  
    for (const int &num : myset){     //iterate over the set 
        if (i++ == index){                       
            return num;
        }
    }
    string msg = "index " + to_string(index) + \ 
        "is out of range"; 
    cout << msg; 
    exit(8);
} 
int main(){ 
    set<int> uniqueItems;        //instantiate a new empty set of integers 

    uniqueItems.insert(10); 
    uniqueItems.insert(20);      //insert three values into the set
    uniqueItems.insert(30); 

    cout << getSetAtIndex(uniqueItems, 1); 
}
```